# How to override configure the environment in kubernetes cluster?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kubernetes, azure-devops, kubernetes-helm

I have a spring boot application, and I created a ConfigMap of my application.proporties. I have some passwords and other sensible date in this file and I would to override some infos there. How can I do for example to override the elasticsearch.url? I would like to override via command line, in the same way to override the values.yaml, is it possible to do this?

```
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: application
data:
  application.properties: |-
    server.port = 8080
    elasticsearch.baseuri = url
```

Comment: Not sure what you are asking... what have you tried?

Comment: I would like to override some variables in this file in the same way of values.yaml. I tried like this helm install chart ./mychart  --set elasticsearch.baseuri=url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this configMap is part of your chart your can just put your secret stuff inside {{ .Values.secretStuff }} and then override it with your helm install command.

Example configMap:

```
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: application
data:
  application.properties: |-
    server.port = 8080
    elasticsearch.baseuri = {{ .Values.elasticSearch.baseUri}}
```

And your helm install command will be

`helm install chart ./mychart --set elasticSearch.baseUri=some-super-secret-stuff`